# C# variable is not the value I want

Tags: c#, variables

This is my code, I am a beginner to C# but used to use python, my problem is that when the user enters their answer the variable answer adds what the user entered onto 48. I have no idea where the data 48 comes from but if the user enters 2 then it will make answer = 50.

```
Random numGen = new Random(); //importing random
int score = 0; //setting a variable

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  //for loop repeating 10 times
{ 
    int num1 = numGen.Next(1, 11); // random number between 1 and 10
    int num2 = numGen.Next(1, 11);
    Console.WriteLine("What is " + num1 + " mutliplied by " + num2 + "? "); 
    //asking a multiplication question
    int answer = 0;
    answer = Console.Read(); //input answer
    int result = num1 * num2; 
    if (result == answer) //checking answer is correct
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Well done that is correct!");
        score = score + 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unlucky that was incorrect");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter for the next question");
    Console.ReadKey();  //waits before closing
}
```

Comment: `Console.Read` doesn't return what you thought it does - it returns a *character code*.

Comment: The ASCII value of '2' is 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`answer = Console.Read();`  reads a character. The character is represented by an ascii number.

Since `48 = '0'`  - `50 = '2'` and so forth, the value seems correct.

You need to use: `Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` to get the expected output.

Better yet use the `Int32.TryParse` flavor to make sure you won't get a runtime exception if the user enters a non numeric input.

```
int answer = 0;
Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-5.0), `Console.Read` only returns the character, not the number. You should consider using `Console.ReadLine` and `int.TryParse` instead.

Answer (score 1):

change this line :

```
answer = Console.Read(); //input answer
```

to this one :

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out answer)
```